# How to identify what is changing styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, icefaces

I have a webpage that has a dropdown menu that displays when the mouse is moved over.  I'm trying to disable that and change it to an onclick with my own javascript.  But I can't stop it from displaying on a mouse over event.  I'm using an icefaces 1.7.2 menubar.  I even set the onmouseout and onmouseover events to '' and it still isn't disabled.

How do I check what is causing the dropdown to show?

Comment: You could see what class is being applied to the dropdown on mouseover, then do a text search across the javascript files for that class name?. Maybe that will get you started?

Comment: Have you checked your CSS for `:hover` yet?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned previously it is very hard to assess your problem with the information provided. ICEfaces 1.7.2 dates back to 2008 so it's important to check that you're using code compatible with their API.
Menus are really quite easy to build with JQuery so if you're using a buggy API, I'd recommend either building your own or using an API with a larger user-base (eg. more available support) such as JQuery UI's Menu API: http://jqueryui.com/menu/
Good luck.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  I have time and I hate working with this legacy system.

Comment: Let me know if that works out; there are literally hundreds of Menu APIs you could use. Try to find one that is compatible with your website's core and if possible with the latest version of JQuery.

Comment: The problem I realized is that my menu is generated dynamically from the database.  I can't find any way to replicate that behavior using just javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

These events are generally jQuery or JavaScript. You must check what changes are being applied in the .js files.

Generally if you're not applying a `.hide()` or `.show()` this can happen if you alter the class of the object. Which will indirectly have a `display: block` which will force it to be visible.

So whatever here is going to happen, or is causing this error is inside the .js file or inside the head section of your web page. Check that.

Sometimes CSS can also do that, like

```
div:hover + select {
  // properties..
}
```

And some other codes can alter that too, so its basically really hard to tell where the error is.